# How to create an r column that depends on previous value of the column being created?

Tags: r

I have a df with two columns `id` and `value`:

```
structure(list(id = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"), value = c(8105.292, 
45000, -41065, 45000, 46054.15, 50000, 50000, 50000, -180000, 
50000, 50000, -180000, 50000, 50000, 50000, 50000)), row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), class = "data.frame", sorted = c("x", "y"))
```

I need to modify the `value` column and/or create a third column described by the following:

- if that row is the first occurrence in the table of the `id`, then return `value`
- Otherwise, return the following: `lag(value) + value`

My problem is the correct calculation needs to reference the modified `lag(value)`... the one that is currently being created. It needs to be applied in sequence, and not reference the original `lag(value)`.

Does this make sense? I have tried applying a function via for loop but am not having luck, and think I am missing something simple. My expected output is:

```
structure(list(id = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"), value = c(8105.292, 
45000, -41065, 45000, 46054.15, 50000, 50000, 50000, -180000, 
50000, 50000, -180000, 50000, 50000, 50000, 50000), expectedvalue = c(8105.292, 
53105.292, 12040.292, 57040.292, 46054.15, 96064.15, 146054.15, 
196054.15, 16054.15, 66054.15, 116054.15, -64954.85, -13945.85, 
36054.15, 86054.15, 136054.15)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), sorted = c("x", 
"y"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want the cumulative sum within each `id`. No need for loops.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(expectedValue = cumsum(value))
#> # A tibble: 16 x 3
#> # Groups:   id [2]
#>    id       value expectedValue
#>    <chr>    <dbl>         <dbl>
#>  1 a        8105.         8105.
#>  2 a       45000         53105.
#>  3 a      -41065         12040.
#>  4 a       45000         57040.
#>  5 b       46054.        46054.
#>  6 b       50000         96054.
#>  7 b       50000        146054.
#>  8 b       50000        196054.
#>  9 b     -180000         16054.
#> 10 b       50000         66054.
#> 11 b       50000        116054.
#> 12 b     -180000        -63946.
#> 13 b       50000        -13946.
#> 14 b       50000         36054.
#> 15 b       50000         86054.
#> 16 b       50000        136054.
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This was exactly it, thank you for pointing me to this

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
df <- structure(list(id = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
                      "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"), value = c(8105.292, 
                                                                         45000, -41065, 45000, 46054.15, 50000, 50000, 50000, -180000, 
                                                                         50000, 50000, -180000, 50000, 50000, 50000, 50000)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                            -16L), class = "data.frame", sorted = c("x", "y"))

df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(value_ = value + lag(value)) %>% mutate(value2 = ifelse(is.na(value_), value, value_)) %>% select(id, value, value2)


   id       value   value2
   <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 a        8105.    8105.
 2 a       45000    53105.
 3 a      -41065     3935 
 4 a       45000     3935 
 5 b       46054.   46054.
 6 b       50000    96054.
 7 b       50000   100000 
 8 b       50000   100000 
 9 b     -180000  -130000 
10 b       50000  -130000 
11 b       50000   100000 
12 b     -180000  -130000 
13 b       50000  -130000 
14 b       50000   100000 
15 b       50000   100000 
16 b       50000   100000
```

If you want to sort it before the group_by, function..

```
df %>% arrange(id, value) %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(value_ = value + lag(value)) %>% mutate(value2 = ifelse(is.na(value_), value, value_)) %>% select(id, value, value2)


   id       value   value2
   <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 a      -41065   -41065 
 2 a        8105.  -32960.
 3 a       45000    53105.
 4 a       45000    90000 
 5 b     -180000  -180000 
 6 b     -180000  -360000 
 7 b       46054. -133946.
 8 b       50000    96054.
 9 b       50000   100000 
10 b       50000   100000 
11 b       50000   100000 
12 b       50000   100000 
13 b       50000   100000 
14 b       50000   100000 
15 b       50000   100000 
16 b       50000   100000
```

Comment: This doesn't give the expected output. I think the OP just wants cumsum per id.